# chef and nginx not serving rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, chef-infra

I am trying to get nginx to serve my rails application (with passenger), but all I am getting is the index.html

sites-enabled/financeRails is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name finance.mbdev-berkshelf;
    root /srv/www/mbdev.com/public_html/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /opt/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/
}
```

I can see on the log that it's working fine:

```
10.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2013:06:27:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36"
```

But I am not getting the rails application...

Note that removing `public/index.html` results in:

```
directory index of "/srv/www/mbdev.com/public_html/public/" is forbidden
```

Comment: in your `config/routes.rb` have you changed `root` to point to the `controller#action` you want to be the default for your rails application?

Comment: I think this is related to rbenv. The application works fine in apache/rvm environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using chef to install nginx and passenger. It appears that if passenger is installed after nginx it does not place the right attributes in /etc/nginx/ngninx.conf  - resulting in rails not working.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned `root :to => "your_index_file_path"` in your routes.

Comment: Yeah, there is a root route, and the application works fine (in another environment). After reading other issues, I am realizing this might be related to rbenv/nginx combination